# How do I create a list of horizontal items?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to create a list of horizontal items so they can be used as navigation. But for some reason, setting display to `inline` is not working. I have also tried setting display to `inline-block` with no results. Any suggestions?

**CSS**

```
#page {
    margin-top: 2em;
    background: #00000
}

#pageborder {
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
}

body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    height: 100%;
    font-family:"Monospace", Lucida Console;
    font-size: 16;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 28pt;
}

h2 {
    margin:0;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    font-size: 22;
}

p {
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}

#header {
    height:50px;
    background-color: none;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
    font-size: 28pt;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 108px;
}

#content {
    position: left;
    color: #5E5849;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1em 2em 4em;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 322px;
}

#sidebar {
    float:right;
    margin-right: 180px;
    position: absolute;
    top:;
    right:0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 250px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #EEEEEE;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

#twitter {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#youtube {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#google {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}


#justin {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#Social {
    border-bottom: solid thin grey;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#profilepic {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
}

.footer {
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 2em;
    color: white;
    clear: both;
    background-color: black;
}

th {
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 2em;
}

#nav {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#999;
}

#nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    height:150px;
    color: red;
    padding-left: 150px;
}

#nav ul li {
    display:inline;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css" />
    <title>Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="pageborder">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="banner.png" width=600 height=74.18>
            </div>
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="links">Links</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <div id="Social"><p><b>Social</b></p></div>
                        <p>
                            <div id="youtube">
                                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/ksheehan77" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="youtube_icon.png" width=36 height=36>
                                </a>
                        </div>
                            <div id="twitter">
                                <a href="http://www.twitter.com/#!/ksheehan77" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="Twitter.png" width=32 height=32>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="justin">
                                <a href="http://www.justin.tv/ksheehan77" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="justintv.png" width=32 height=32>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="google">
                                <a rel="author" href="https://profiles.google.com/110661467085975877308/" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-32.png" width="32" height="32">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </p>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="content"> 
                <h2>Content</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec luctus nunc eget sem iaculis pharetra. Integer sodales interdum accumsan. In et diam neque. Praesent eget erat id lectus rutrum placerat a a purus. Integer molestie arcu vel orci iaculis sagittis consequat mauris hendrerit. Fusce placerat leo ac tortor fringilla posuere. Quisque et enim nisl, eu laoreet nibh. Sed vitae turpis leo. Etiam dictum pretium faucibus. Nam quis ornare nibh. Sed ultricies lacinia dolor ac ullamcorper. Sed dictum enim ut urna consequat quis bibendum mi eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec blandit nisi vitae dui blandit ultrices.</p>

                    <p>Aliquam enim ligula, pharetra at scelerisque eu, imperdiet vel lorem. Phasellus faucibus nunc ac purus imperdiet eleifend. Praesent id scelerisque massa. Suspendisse sed ornare lectus. Duis eget lacus quam, quis pharetra magna. Phasellus rhoncus, lectus et dictum accumsan, diam justo volutpat urna, ac auctor leo velit in augue. Proin eget nisi vel turpis hendrerit tempor sed a odio. Phasellus lacinia placerat lobortis. Vestibulum consequat bibendum semper. Vivamus cursus eros non felis gravida fermentum. Donec pulvinar, nisl a varius volutpat, ante lectus varius erat, ac sodales nisl nulla sed eros. Nam bibendum cursus bibendum. Nam id orci vitae odio consequat vestibulum eu vitae ipsum. Fusce ullamcorper pretium est, eget elementum mauris tristique vitae.</p>

                    <p>Suspendisse facilisis mauris eget mi tempus porta. Morbi viverra, libero sed posuere porta, est purus commodo nunc, ac interdum lacus eros et turpis. Pellentesque consequat sagittis elit vel imperdiet. Pellentesque elementum, eros eget vestibulum tempor, justo metus volutpat purus, sed viverra justo odio et erat. Maecenas id urna quam. Praesent auctor congue venenatis. Aenean dolor nisl, viverra vitae ornare sed, pretium sed nibh. Pellentesque pharetra pellentesque ipsum, in ornare lacus iaculis vel. Aliquam quis arcu lectus, eu pretium est. Integer a urna dui, vel tincidunt magna.</p>

                    <p>Nulla mauris felis, mollis at egestas at, suscipit at sem. Donec tincidunt, tellus at consectetur consectetur, elit nisi ullamcorper dolor, vel posuere odio sapien quis ligula. Proin nunc arcu, commodo id hendrerit pulvinar, hendrerit a ligula. Nulla sagittis iaculis est, eleifend mollis dolor ullamcorper a. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc non urna non nulla mollis rhoncus. Mauris eu urna tortor, et tincidunt diam.</p>

                    <p>Ut vehicula sodales nisi eu viverra. Donec nec sollicitudin nisi. Quisque tristique massa vel felis gravida iaculis. Proin a urna quis lacus facilisis viverra. In lacus nunc, faucibus sed luctus sit amet, tempor vitae nunc. Sed erat urna, ultricies non pretium at, vehicula id nibh. Sed sed dolor nisl. Duis nisi felis, euismod sit amet pulvinar ac, hendrerit vel tellus. Fusce vehicula tristique pellentesque. Cras molestie laoreet viverra.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <center>
        <div class="footer">Kieran Sheehan - 2012</div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working here http://jsfiddle.net/heera/rb7B4/

Comment: `display:inline` automatically sets the list-style-type to `none`, anyway I tried your code it's working!

Comment: instead of `display:inline;` use `float:left;`

Comment: Are you sure of the way you're include the CSS style sheet? if not: inside the head `<link type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" >`

Comment: What browser are you using?  It works here.

Comment: please show us the full code for the HTML and the CSS.

Comment: Ok it has been updated to show the full code

Comment: Include a doctype (like `<!doctype html>`) at the top of your HTML. Depending on the browser, a missing doctype can lead to serious styling problems.

Answer (score 1):

Works using:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #nav{
        width:100%;
        height:30px;
        background-color:#999;
      }

      #nav ul{
        height:150px;
        color: red;
        padding-left: 150px;
      }

      #nav ul li{
        display:inline;
        list-style-type: none;}
    </style>
   </head>

   <div id="nav">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="links">Links</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</html>
```

Try refreshing your browser using Ctrl+F5 - it may have cached some results that didn't work.

Comment: @Mark still no luck. Will I post all the code. There is not that much? Could I have something conflicting with the other tags

Comment: @KSheehan77 What browser are you trying?  Is your Template.css file in the same directory as your html file?  I copied & pasted your code and it worked immediately for me.

Answer (score 0):

works well for me. Do you have some other css rules that could conflict with these ones? You could check which styles are applied to your "li" with the chrome developper console, maybe.

By the way, "list-style-type" is meant to be used with "ul" or ol", not with "li".

Comment: How would I go about doing that?
I also removed list-style-type
Didn't know you could not use it in li

Comment: if you're using chrome, right click on one of your "li" and then click on "inspect element". This will open the developper console on the "Elements" tab with your "li" preselected. On the right, you can see all the styles applied to it. This could give you an idea of what might be going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Although your css does not include such a property, make sure your li elements don't clear (i.e. clear:left / clear:right / clear:both)

To double check, add this into your css (using !important is bad, only use it for testing)

```
#nav ul li{
    clear: none !important;
}
```

try adding floating too to see if you manage to get your elements to appear on the same line. If you still have no luck, there is definitely something wrong with your setup that's not apparent from the code you pasted.

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav ul{
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
height:150px;
color: red;
***padding-left: 150px;***}
```

I think here you did mistake; Remove padding for ul, might b it'll work